# I encountered some thing weird code in Dynamic memory allocation for 2D arrays in C++? please explain me what is this?

Tags: c++, pointers, nspointerarray

code:- `p = new int *[5];`
 where p is a pointer & declared as `int **P;` 
 Please explain me that why there is a `*` in between new and [5].

Comment: Better use of your time: learn about smart pointers and containers.

Comment: @Molybdenum Oxide Looks like the multiply operator.

Comment: `p = new *[5];` is not valid code - it should be `p = new int*[5];`.

Comment: I  have edited, review now.\

Comment: Remember in C++, by virtue of its C roots, pointers and arrays are interchangeable.

Comment: You probably should show a little more code but still less than 20 lines. [mcve]

Comment: @tadman what do you mean by  pointers and arrays are interchangeable.

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide I've added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When allocating an array using `new` you need to specify the type. The general pattern is:

```
type* x = new type[n];
```

Where `type` is the base type, `x` is the variable, and `n` is the number of entries. You can make this a pointer type by adding `*` to both sides:

```
type** x = new type*[n];
```

You can continue this indefinitely:

```
type**** x = new type***[n];
```

Though in practice you'd rarely see that since excessively deep structures like that are nothing but trouble.

In C++, by virtue of its C heritage, pointers and arrays are interchangeable, as in both these definitions are basically equivalent:

```
void f(int* x)
void f(int x[])
```

Internally you can use `x` as either a pointer or an array, or both:

```
int y = x[0];
int z = *x;
```

Likewise these are identical:

```
int y = x[1];
int z = *(x + 1);
```

In general the distinction between `x[n]` and `*(x + n)` is largely irrelevant, the compiler treats both as the same and the emitted machine code is identical. The `[]` notation is just a syntax element that helps make the code easier to follow.